# 3D Vectors - Align a vector's coordinate system to a normal

Tags: math, vector, 3d, transform, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to align a coordinate system to a normal direction, in a way I only input X,Y,Z and the direction of the normal and the Y-rotation of the coordinate, to get the new X,Y,Z from the new aligned coordinate system.

A function that would look like this:

```
func transform(coordinate: XYZposition, to: XYZnormal, withY:Radians){
    //missing mathematic
    //rotate coordinates        
    return XYZpositionOfNewSystem
}
```

Here is an image representing visualize what I want to achieve. The axis are the representation of the coordinate system. First coordinate system is the original one, and the 2 on the right are the rotated ones.

[image]

**Why 2 examples on the right?**

As you can see, when aligning it to a face-normal, there is one free axis. The Y axis can take any rotation and still be aligned to the face.

That's why a rotation needs to be given to the function so it applies this Y-rotation as well.

I've found some maths on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site ([Rotate 3D coordinate system such that z-axis is parallel to a given vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542801/rotate-3d-coordinate-system-such-that-z-axis-is-parallel-to-a-given-vector)), but I'm lost if this is what I need, and I'm kind of lost on the maths applied and the symbols used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [the answer you cited](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/543538), implemented using python and numpy, and exchanging the roles of `y` and `z` to fit your needs:

```py
from numpy import array, dot, cross, arccos, sin, cos
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

def angle(u,v):
    return arccos(1 - cosine(u,v))

# assumes all four vectors are normalized
def get_transform_matrix(orig_system, n):
    j = orig_system[:,1]
    b = cross(j, n)
    theta = angle(j, n)
    q0 = cos(theta/2)
    q1,q2,q3 = sin(theta/2) * b
    Q = array([
         [q0**2 + q1**2 - q2**2 - q3**2, 2*(q1*q3+q0*q2), 2*(q1*q2-q0*q3)],
         [2*(q3*q1-q0*q2), q0**2 - q1**2 - q2**2 + q3**2, 2*(q3*q2+q0*q1)],
         [2*(q2*q1+q0*q3), 2*(q2*q3-q0*q1), q0**2 - q1**2 + q2**2 - q3**2]
    ])
    return Q
```

To transform a vector `p` into the new system, just compute `Q @ p`:

```py
from numpy import eye, sqrt

orig_system = eye(3)
n = array([0,1,1]) / sqrt(2)

Q = get_transform_matrix(orig_system, n)

print(Q)
# [[ 0.9267767   0.          0.        ]
#  [ 0.          0.78033009  0.5       ]
#  [ 0.         -0.5         0.78033009]]

p = array([10, 20, 30])

print(Q @ p)
# [ 9.26776695 30.60660172 13.40990258]
```

Please do test it extensively!! I tested with a few different vectors and it looked okay, but I cannot guarantee that there are no mistakes.

Comment: Will test it right now! Will let you if it worked, I'd need to translate to Metal first, I'm using it on a shader for calculating UV coords.